# Ask for a solution about python combination algorithm in the real world practice

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I'm  writing a smart counter program for a fruit shop, here is what it does:

When customer are buying `n` type of fruit, this program will check if some/all of these fruit are fit with a/several kinds of discount privilege, if so, these fruit will enjoy a relative discount.

A specific Discount definition is like this( the tag_clause number each Discount contains is uncertain, and every fruit has several tags ):

```
<discount name='aaa' discount='90%'>
    <tag_clause>bestseller</tag>
    <tag_clause>juicy</tag>
    <tag_clause>badseller</tag>        
</discount>
```

it means: if customer wants to enjoy this discount, he/she will at least buy three diffrent kinds of fruit, and each of their tags at lease matches one of the tag_clauses in the Discount definition.

Take an example: if you are buying *apple*(tags:**bestseller, juicy**), *watermelon*(tags:**juicy**) and *banana*(tags:**badseller**), then you can enjoy a *90%* discount.

Since every Discount is consists of several(uncertain) number of tag_clauses, the challenge is to find all possible combinations which several fruit may match Discount A, another several match Discount B, and the rest may match Discount C or match nothing(will be saled in original price).

Here are the definitions of model `Fruit` and `Discount` :

```
class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.weight = Decimal('0.0')
        self.price = Decimal('0.00')
        self.tags = None

class Discount(object):      
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.discount = Decimal('0.0')
        self.clauseTagNum = 0
        self.clauseTags = []
```

**My question is** : given n types of fruit, and m number of Discount, try to find out all possible try-match combinations. That's say, I want to generate all combinations (so I can filter them), but have no clue about how to generate them all.

For example, if customer is buying fruit `A, B, C, D, E`, and here we have three different Discount `Disc-3, Disc-2_1, Disc-2_2`, their tag_clause number are 3, 2, 2. Part of possible combinations are:

```
A,B,C try-match Disc-3 | D,E try-match Disc-2_2
B,C,D try-match Disc-3 | A,E try-match Disc-2_1
C,E try-match Disc-2_2 | A,D try-match Disc-2_1 | B try-match nothing
A,B try-match Disc-2_1 | C,E try-match Disc-2_1 | D try-match nothing
```

Big thanks for your time.

Comment: A few clarifying questions: Does each tag_clause need to be fulfilled for the discount to apply? Did you really mean 90% discount, or 10%?

Comment: This problem looks like a multidimensional knapsack problem, so it could be NP-hard. For a normal amount of groceries, that shouldn't be a problem as long as your algorithm isn't *too* inefficient, but something like brute-forcing all possible discount combinations could cause so much lag as to make your program unusable.

Comment: What part of this are you stuck on? For example, maybe you want to generate all combinations (so you can filter them), but don't know how to generate all combinations. In that case, that's a specific question you could ask, instead of just saying "Here's my assignment, what do I do?" Or, if you know this isn't exactly solvable without taking way too long, and you want help implementing an optimization algorithm that you found online but don't understand one of the steps, show us the parts you do understand and where you get lost.

Comment: Why are these discounts based on types of fruit? If I want to buy 3 boxes of apples, am I going to want to buy a single watermelon and a single banana just to qualify for a discount? Do numbers of each kind of fruit matter?

Comment: @user2357112 question 1: Yes,each tag_clause need to be fulfilled, and the discount here means 10% off | question 2: Buy 3 boxes of apples would be another question, but thanks for mentioning this idea,still.Finally thanks for your solution analysis.

Comment: @abarnert I updated the question to _don't know how to generate all combinations_ ,and give my thinking result in the question.

Comment: @Lyfing: OK, that's now a good question. (The fact that senshin could write such a great answer almost proves that it was a good question.)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following:

```
import itertools

class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, name=None, tags=None):
        self.name = name
        self.tags = tags
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Discount:
    def __init__(self, name=None, clause_tags=None):
        self.name = name
        if clause_tags is None:
            self.clause_tags_num = 0
            self.clause_tags = []
        else:
            self.clause_tags_num = len(clause_tags)
            self.clause_tags = clause_tags
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

A = Fruit('A', ['bestseller'])
B = Fruit('B', ['juicy', 'delicious'])
C = Fruit('C', [])
D = Fruit('D', ['badseller', 'juicy'])
E = Fruit('E', ['bestseller', 'delicious'])
fruits = [A, B, C, D, E]

Disc21 = Discount('Disc-2_1', ['delicious', 'bestseller'])
Disc22 = Discount('Disc-2_2', ['juicy', 'delicious'])
Disc3 = Discount('Disc-3', ['bestseller', 'juicy', 'badseller'])
discounts = [Disc21, Disc22, Disc3]

def match(fruits, discount):
    '''Determine whether a given set of fruits earns a given discount.'''
    # we must have at least as many fruits as clause tags
    if len(fruits) < discount.clause_tags_num:
        return False
    else:
        # now, we check to see that every clause tag in the discount is
        # present in at least one of the fruits.
        discount_tags = set(discount.clause_tags)
        fruit_tags = set()
        for fruit in fruits:
            fruit_tags = fruit_tags.union(set(tag for tag in fruit.tags))
        if fruit_tags.issuperset(discount_tags):
            return True
        else:
            return False

def match_fruits_to_discounts(fruits, discounts):
    successful_combinations = {discount: [] for discount in discounts}
    for discount in discounts:
        # iterate over all possible amounts of fruit that at least have one
        # fruit per clause tag in the discount
        for i in range(discount.clause_tags_num, len(fruits)):
            # try all combinations for each amount of fruit
            for fruit_combination in itertools.combinations(fruits, i):
                if match(fruit_combination, discount):
                    successful_combinations[discount].append(fruit_combination)
    return successful_combinations

result = match_fruits_to_discounts(fruits, discounts)
for key in result:
    print(key)
    print(result[key])
```

First, we define the `Fruit` and `Discount` classes (I modified them a bit for brevity and readability, but it should be clear how to alter them to your needs). Then, we define some `Fruit` and `Discount` objects.

The function `match` determines whether a given set of fruit suffice to meet a given discount. I *believe* I have implemented this the same way you have described, but it behooves you to verify this, as I was unclear on whether or not a single fruit is supposed to be able to satisfy multiple tag clauses.

Finally, the function `match_fruits_to_discounts` finds all combinations of the `fruits` argument that match any of the discounts given in the `discounts` argument. The program will print out which sets of fruits satisfy a given discount at the end.

I think what you may have been having trouble with is that you were not aware of `itertools.combinations(iterable, r)`, which, as the name suggests, generates combinations of `r` elements selected from `iterable` (and since these are combinations, order is irrelevant).

As mentioned in the comments, this is probably NP-Hard, meaning that if you try to run this for too many fruits or too many discounts, the number of loop iterations in the last function will explode, and you will find yourself, as they say, screwed.

---

In response to your comment, here is a version of `match` that accomodates repeated tags in a given `Discount`:

```
def match(fruits, discount):
    # no explicit check for number of tags needed here
    discount_tags = discount.clause_tags[:] # make a copy
    fruit_tags = []
    for fruit in fruits:
        for tag in fruit.tags:
            fruit_tags.append(tag)
    # check that every tag in discount_tags is also represented in
    # fruit_tags the same number of times
    for tag in discount_tags:
        if tag not in fruit_tags:
            return False
        else:
            fruit_tags.remove(tag)
    # if we haven't returned False so far, that means that every discount
    # tag has also been a fruit tag, and so we're happy.
    return True
```

Note that this implementation still assumes that no `Fruit` will have the same tag more than once. I assume this will be the case, because I don't see why one would want to have a `Fruit` that is double-`bestselling` or whatever.

Comment: Your solution works great when the Discount's tags are unique among each other, such as Discount_A['bestseller', 'badseller', 'juicy'], but when the discount's tags becomes not unique, then your `match()` function will fail. Such as a Discount, it has 2 tag clauses:['badseller', 'badseller'], and it will provide a discount for 50% off! And ... you know, you can buy as much as you want in a 50% off price, all you need to do is just make sure one of your many fruit  is a 'badseller'. Anyway, big thanks for your time!

Comment: @Lyfing Good point, I didn't think that you would need discounts with repeated tag clauses. See the edit I made at the bottom of the answer; that version of `match` should accomodate `Discount`s with repeated tags.

Comment: Yes, you're right. And you just push me back to the start point to reconsider about the whole idea and rules about Discount, which makes me find that your idea makes more sense. And thanks for your solution in `match()`function, it helps me a lot(in fact it helps my pc buddy a lot **:)**).

Answer (score 0):

Given these fruits and discounts:

```
class Fruit(object):
    def __init__(self, name, tags):
        self.name = name
        self.tags = tags
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Discount(object):      
    def __init__(self, name, tags):
        self.name = name
        self.tags = tags
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

apple = Fruit('apple', ['bestseller','juicy'])
banana = Fruit('banana', ['badseller'])
watermelon = Fruit('watermelon', ['juicy'])
melon = Fruit('melon', ['juicy'])

discount_a = Discount('a', ['bestseller','juicy','badseller'])
discount_b = Discount('b', ['juicy','bestseller'])

fruits = (apple,banana,watermelon,melon)
discounts = (discount_a,discount_b)
```

We can generate the list of all possible combinations:

```
from operator import attrgetter

class Match(object):
    def __init__(self, fruit, tag):
        self.fruit = fruit
        self.tag = tag
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.fruit.name,self.tag)

def analyze(fruits,discounts):
    for discount in discounts:
        matching = matching_fruits_for_tags(fruits,discount.tags)
        if matching:
            for perm in permutations(matching):
                print discount, ':', sorted(perm, key=attrgetter('fruit.name'))

def matching_fruits_for_tags(fruits,tags):
    matching = [
        [Match(f,tag) for f in fruits if tag in f.tags] 
        for tag in tags]
    if all(matching):
        return matching

def permutations(matching):
    perm = []
    for fruits in matching:
        if perm:
            perm = [list(set(p+[f])) for f in fruits for p in perm]
        else:
            perm = [[f] for f in fruits]
    return perm

analyze(fruits,discounts)
```

It will print:

```
a : [apple (juicy), apple (bestseller), banana (badseller)]
a : [apple (bestseller), banana (badseller), watermelon (juicy)]
a : [apple (bestseller), banana (badseller), melon (juicy)]
b : [apple (bestseller), apple (juicy)]
b : [apple (bestseller), watermelon (juicy)]
b : [apple (bestseller), melon (juicy)]
```

I'm using a `Match` object, so the tag is shown next to the fruit name. The `matching_fruits_for_tags` collects all matching fruits per discount tag. For example for discount_a:

```
[[apple (bestseller)],
 [apple (juicy), watermelon (juicy), melon (juicy)],
 [banana (badseller)]]
```

The `permutations` generates all possible permutations from this:

```
[[apple (juicy), apple (bestseller), banana (badseller)],
 [banana (badseller), apple (bestseller), watermelon (juicy)],
 [melon (juicy), apple (bestseller), banana (badseller)]]
```

Where all 3 permutations has apple (bestseller) and banana (badseller) and the 3 possible variations for (juicy).

For discount_b the `matching_fruits_for_tags` returns:

```
[[apple (juicy), watermelon (juicy), melon (juicy)], 
 [apple (bestseller)]]
```

We have 3 variations for (juicy) and one for (bestseller). So the result of `permutations`:

```
[[apple (juicy), apple (bestseller)],
 [watermelon (juicy), apple (bestseller)],
 [melon (juicy), apple (bestseller)]]
```

Comment: It's a little bit too easy for what I'm looking for, thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: I added a new getCombinations function. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Recheck my questions maybe helpreful.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't read your post carefully. I rewrote my answer. Are you looking for that output?

Comment: You are really a nice guy.Thank you.